# Eclipse CVS - warning: commitinfo line contains no format strings

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, cvs

I'm getting the following error: "commitinfo line contains no format strings [..] Appending defaults (" %r/%p %s")"
when trying to commit a project to CVS using Eclipse (juno) and Ubuntu 12.04.

I couldn't find a solution elsewhere. The directory /usr/local/sbin is empty.

Thanks in advance, below is the full trace

```
The server reported an error while performing the "cvs commit" command.
myProject: cvs commit: warning: commitinfo line contains no format strings:
myProject:     "/usr/local/sbin/validarcommit"  
myProject: Appending defaults (" %r/%p %s"), but please be aware that this usage is
myProject: deprecated.  
myProject: cvs commit: warning: commitinfo line contains no format strings:
myProject:     "/usr/local/sbin/validarcommit"   
myProject: Appending defaults (" %r/%p %s"), but please be aware that this usage is
myProject: deprecated.  
myProject: cvs commit: warning: verifymsg line doesn't contain any format strings:
myProject:     "/export/cvs/CVSROOT/validarmensajecommit"  
myProject: Appending default format string (" %l"), but be aware that this usage is
myProject: deprecated.  
myProject: cvs [commit aborted]: Message verification failed
```

Comment: Is your cvs repository local or on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CVS repository includes a `commitinfo` file and a `verifymsg` file.

A `commitinfo` file is intended to run validations on each commit. From this error it seems that the file contains two lines that match your commit, both of which run the command `/usr/local/sbin/validarcommit` on the server.

A `verifymsg` file is intended to run validations for CVS log operations. It appears that your `verifymsg` file includes a line that calls the command `/export/cvs/CVSROOT/validarmensajecommit` on the server.

In general, CVS expects `commitinfo` and `verifymsg` validation commands to contain formatting expressions, which CVS will replace with the file being committed, the version and so on. This is because the commands are expected to actually look at the file or the log line, and see whether the changes in it are acceptable, according to the standards of your developer team.

Apparently, whoever wrote the `commitinfo` and `verifymsg` for your particular CVS repository did not adhere to these instructions, and just placed commands there without formatting expressions. Thus you are getting warnings from the server about the lack of those formatting commands.

You should contact whoever is in charge of the CVS repository and has added the `commitinfo` and `verifymsg` files there, and tell them that the current files are written in a deprecated format, and that they should add the formatting characters to them.

- [Information about the `commitinfo` file](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#The%20commitinfo%20And%20loginfo%20And%20rcsinfo%20Files)
- [Information about the `verifymsg` file](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#The%20verifymsg%20And%20rcsinfo%20Files)